# Preflight request doesn't pass access control check

Tags: php, angular, rest, cors

Trying to make a JWT authorized json rest api request from my angular 8 web application, when it gives the above error. All sensible CORS configuration steps have been followed, and then relaxing of the rules to the point where it still doesn't work and I have turned to you guys for help.

So in terms of CORS config, on the php side of things I started with :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200");
header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

I slackened things off a bit to :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

But then I read in the CORS docs that Access-Control-Allow-Headers does not allow *, so I reverted that line.

Currently I have :

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json, text/plain, */*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, PUT, POST, DELETE");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization");
```

The error I get is :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost/api/controllers/asset.php/' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

This is the header information for the request from the network tab in debug tools (Chrome).

> Provisional headers are shown Accept: application/json, text/plain,
>   */* Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOm51bGwsImF1ZCI6IlRIRV9BVURJRU5DRSIsImlhdCI6MTU2NjYyOTIxNywibmJmIjoxNTY2NjI5MjE5LCJleH....redacted

This is running on apache with php 7.2

I would expect the new relaxed CORS settings  to work, but still I get this error.

How can I tweak the CORS settings to satisfy the pre-flight request?

Comment: Check the network tab in your broeser's developer tools. You should see a request with method "OPTIONS" which is the preflight request. It seems from the error above that this request isn't getting an HTTP ok response

Answer (score 0):

I created a framework called [Willow](https://github.com/RyanNerd/willow). This is the [code](https://github.com/RyanNerd/willow/blob/master/public/index.php) I use that gets past the CORS insanity.

```
    $requestMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

    // Is this a pre-flight request (the request method is OPTIONS)? Then start output buffering.
    if ($requestMethod === 'OPTIONS') {
        ob_start();
    }

    // Allow for all origins and credentials. Also allow GET, POST, PATCH, and OPTIONS request verbs
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE');

    // If this is a pre-flight request (the request method is OPTIONS)? Then flush the output buffer and exit.
    if ($requestMethod === 'OPTIONS') {
        ob_end_flush();
        exit();
    }
```

HTH

Comment: This is precisely the answer. I will look at your Willow Framework with keen interest, but for now the output buffering solution works like an absolute charm. Thank you so much.